# What is the alternative for BackgroundWorker in Windows 8.1 Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am migrating my Windows Phone App to Windows Universal Apps. In Phone App, I used BackgroundWorker for database retrieval and then show in UI. Below is the class which I prepared in Windows Phone 8 and how it was called.

```
public class TestBackgroundWorker
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator;

    public delegate void functionToRunInBackground();
    public functionToRunInBackground currentFunctionToExecute;

    public delegate void callbackFunction();
    public callbackFunction functionToSendResult;

    private bool isCancellationSupported;


    private string message;


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="functionNameToExecute">specifies function name to be executed in background</param>
    /// <param name="isCancellable">Flag which specifies whether the operation is cancellable or not</param>
    /// <param name="functionNameWhichGetsResult">Specifies call back function to be executed after the completion of operation</param>
    public MCSBackgroundWorker(functionToRunInBackground functionNameToExecute, bool isCancellable, string messageToDisplay, callbackFunction functionNameWhichGetsResult)
    {
        currentFunctionToExecute = functionNameToExecute;
        functionToSendResult = functionNameWhichGetsResult;
        isCancellationSupported = isCancellable;
        message = messageToDisplay;
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = isCancellable;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        deactivateProgressIndicator();
        functionToSendResult();
    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentFunctionToExecute != null)
        {
            currentFunctionToExecute();
        }
    }


    public void cancelBackgroundOperation()
    {
        if (isCancellationSupported == true)
        {
            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        activateProgressIndicator();
    }


    void activateProgressIndicator()
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            var currentPage = App.RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
            SystemTray.SetIsVisible(currentPage, true);
            SystemTray.SetOpacity(currentPage, 0.5);
            SystemTray.SetBackgroundColor(currentPage, Colors.White);
            SystemTray.SetForegroundColor(currentPage, Colors.Black);

            progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
            progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            progressIndicator.Text = message;

            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(currentPage, progressIndicator);

        });

    }

    void deactivateProgressIndicator()
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (progressIndicator != null)
            {
                var currentPage = App.RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
                progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                SystemTray.SetIsVisible(currentPage, false);

            }

        });
    }


    public bool isBackgroundWorkerBusy()
    {
        return backgroundWorker != null ? backgroundWorker.IsBusy : false;
    }

}
```

}

And calling that as below to run the process in background.

```
private void loadReports()
    {
        bgWorker = new TestBackgroundWorker(loadReportsFromDB, true, "Loading...", showReports);
        bgWorker.Start();
    }
```

Here, loadReprtsFromDB and showReports are two functions.

Questions:

1. Can anyone suggest how to achieve same thing in Windows 8.1?
2. Is there any alternative for `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, even for the desktop, the `Task<T>` and `Progress<T>` classes offer a nice alternative to `BackgroundWorker`, and they are both supported on Windows Phone 8.1. The `Task<T>` class provides the mechanism to start and then cleanly wait for background operations, while the `Progress<T>` class provides the mechanism for reporting progress (not part of your example or question, but I mention it because that's the one thing `Task` along with `async`/`await` doesn't provide from `BackgroundWorker`).

Your example could be changed to something like this:

```
public class TestBackgroundWorker
{
    private Task _task;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource;

    public CancellationToken CancellationToken
    {
        get { return _cancelSource != null ? _cancelSource.Token : null; }
    }

    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator;

    public readonly Action<TestBackgroundWorker> currentFunctionToExecute;

    private string message;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="functionNameToExecute">specifies function name to be executed in background</param>
    /// <param name="isCancellable">Flag which specifies whether the operation is cancellable or not</param>
    /// <param name="functionNameWhichGetsResult">Specifies call back function to be executed after the completion of operation</param>
    public MCSBackgroundWorker(Action<TestBackgroundWorker> functionNameToExecute, bool isCancellable, string messageToDisplay)
    {
        currentFunctionToExecute = functionNameToExecute;
        _cancelSource = isCancellable ? new CancellationTokenSource() : null;
        message = messageToDisplay;
    }

    public void cancelBackgroundOperation()
    {
        if (_cancelSource != null)
        {
            _cancelSource.Cancel();
        }
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        activateProgressIndicator();
        _task = Task.Run(() => currentFunctionToExecute(this));
        await _task;
        _task = null;
        deactivateProgressIndicator();
    }

    void activateProgressIndicator()
    {
        // In theory, you should not need to use Dispatcher here with async/await.
        // But without a complete code example, it's impossible for me to
        // say for sure, so I've left it as-is.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            var currentPage = App.RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
            SystemTray.SetIsVisible(currentPage, true);
            SystemTray.SetOpacity(currentPage, 0.5);
            SystemTray.SetBackgroundColor(currentPage, Colors.White);
            SystemTray.SetForegroundColor(currentPage, Colors.Black);

            progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
            progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            progressIndicator.Text = message;

            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(currentPage, progressIndicator);
        });
    }

    void deactivateProgressIndicator()
    {
        // Likewise.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (progressIndicator != null)
            {
                var currentPage = App.RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
                progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                SystemTray.SetIsVisible(currentPage, false);
            }
        });
    }

    public bool isBackgroundWorkerBusy()
    {
        return _task != null;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it something like this:

```
private async Task loadReports()
{
    bgWorker = new TestBackgroundWorker(loadReportsFromDB, true, "Loading...");
    await bgWorker.Start();
    showReports();
}

void loadReportsFromDB(TaskBackgroundWorker worker)
{
    while (...)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return; // or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

To deal with cancellation, the `functionNameToExecute` delegate would need to be for a method that accepts an instance of `TaskBackgroundWorker` as a parameter, so that it can retrieve the `CancellationToken` property value to check for cancellation (similar to the `DoWork()` event handler…though your code example didn't actually suggest any mechanism by which the actual background operation code would even detect cancellation).

Note that with `async`/`await`, your task can also return a value if you like, via the `Task<T>` type instead of `Task`. The above example could easily be modified to accommodate that, and that feature of `async`/`await` is one of the biggest reasons I prefer it over `BackgroundWorker` (which has no clean, compiler-supported mechanism for returning results from the background operation).

**Caveat:** Lacking a complete code example to start with, there is no point for me to try to actually compile and test any of the code. So the above is strictly "browser-authored". It should suffice for the purposes of illustration, but I apologize in advance for any typos that might exist.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I will try this.But why callBackFunction parameter was removed?. Can you answer my second question also?

Comment: I removed that parameter because it's not needed with the `async`/`await` pattern. As I've shown in the example calling code, instead of passing a delegate to be invoked, you can just call the method directly after `await`ing the `async` method. As for the second question, it's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886107/phoneapplicationservice-current-state-equivalent-in-windows-8